# Java en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo esta curiosa situacion en el editor de codigo java en AndroidStudio, declaro una sentencia en una linea y me la marca como correcta, pero declaro lo mismo en 2 lineas y me la resalta en rojo diciendo "Identifier expected,Unexpected token" . Segun yo ambas formas de escribir son válidas; pero para el editor esta mal. Alguien me puede aclarar el por qué me lanza error(lineas rojas) ?? Cuál es la diferencia entre las 2 sintaxis ? Si es que la hay.

```
package com.example.codingcap7;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   int a;             //--ESTA LINEA ESTA NORMAL
   a=12;              //--ESTA LINEA SE MARCA TODO EN ROJO CON ESTE
                      //  MENSAJE "Identifier expected,Unexpected token"

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   }

}
```

Y este seria el que si me reconoce como correcto:

```
package com.example.codingcap7;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int a=12;     //-- ESTA LINEA ES CORRECTA

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, si vas a declarar una variable y asignarle un valor la forma correcta debe ser:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   int a = 12; 
   //a=12;       

   ...
   ...
}
```

Ya que el valor asignado se aplicará a toda la clase.

---

Pero si vas a declarar una variable y realizar la asignación posteriormente, esta debe ser realizada dentro de algún método o subclase:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       int a = 12; 
       //a=12;       

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //Asignación de valor para la variable a;
        a=12;    

   }

}
```